# Flex content size transition not filling whole flex container

Tags: css, flexbox

I'm trying to create a static-width navigation bar with icons. When the user hovers over an icon, it will expand to show more text. If no item is being hovered over, the current page will be expanded.

This is what I have so far: (https://jsfiddle.net/vajmhfg3/)

```css
nav {
  background-color: red;
  display: flex;
  width: 350px;
  height: 50px;
}

div {
  flex: 0 0 50px;
  background-color: white;
  border: 1px solid black;
  transition: 400ms;
}

nav:hover>div:hover,
nav:not(:hover)>.current {
  transition: 400ms;
  flex: 1 1;
  background-color: #0A0;
}
```

```html
<nav>
  <div>A</div>
  <div class="current">B</div>
  <div>C</div>
  <div>D</div>
  <div>E</div>
</nav>
```

This works fine when hovering over one item, and then hovering over an adjacent item. However, when quickly hovering over an item, moving over an adjacent item to an item two away, the navigation items don't take up the whole width of the navigation bar. In the demo, you'll see red to show the whole width.

What's preventing the items from taking up the whole width of the navigation bar?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to have `flex-grow:1` and `flex-shrink: 0;` on all your children. On the ones you want to grow, place a higher `flex-grow`. For example: `3`.

```css
nav {
  background-color: red;
  
  display: flex;
  
  width: 350px;
  height: 50px;
}

div {
  flex: 1 0 auto;
  background-color: white;
  border: 1px solid black;
  
  transition: 400ms;
}

nav:hover > div:hover,
nav:not(:hover) > .current {
  flex: 3 0 auto;
  background-color: #0A0;
  transition: 400ms;
}
```

```html
<nav>
  <div>A</div>
  <div class="current">B</div>
  <div>C</div>
  <div>D</div>
  <div>E</div>
</nav>
```

The higher the `flex-grow` the more it will push the other elements. Having `flex-grow` on all will make them always push till the limits of their parent.

---

Here's [a little toy](https://jsfiddle.net/websiter/no73st0h/) I made when I first discovered `flexbox`. You might find it useful. You can add / delete items in the html structure and will adjust.

Comment: This is pretty much what I'm after. If you move your cursor between C, D, and E quickly, A will grow a little. This is certainly good enough for what I need to do, but I'm curious why the items with flex-grow > 0 aren't filling up the whole width.

Comment: @BenWoodworth: you will always have only one item growing: the one you currently hover. If you overlap the animation of more than 1 other element, those 2 (or more) elements will be decreasing, while only the hovered one will be growing. The more elements transitioning simultaneously, the bigger the gap.